# How to solve the following recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I am not familiar with recurrence-solving techniques outside of the master theorem, recursion trees, and the substitution method. I am guessing that solving the following recurrence for a big-O bound does not utilize one of those methods:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 2T(n-2) + 1
```

Comment: What is the base case for `T(n)` ?

Comment: This is a great spot to use the annihilator method... which I don't actually know how to do. :-)

Comment: A base case is not provided. I'm guessing it is not needed to achieve a big-O bound?

Comment: Hint: T(n) = 2^n. Additionally, look at [this math stackexchange question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316301/if-tn-tn-1-2tn-2).

Answer (score 3):

We can make the substitution `U(n) = T(n) + 1/2` and then get a recurrence

```
U(n) = T(n) + 1/2
     = T(n-1) + 2T(n-2) + 1 + 1/2
     = T(n-1) + 1/2 + 2(T(n-2) + 1/2)
     = U(n-1) + 2U(n-2),
```

which is a little magic but, as templatetypedef mentions, the magic can be created with the annihilator method. Now we just have to solve the linear homogeneous recurrence. The characteristic polynomial `x^2 - x - 2` factors as `(x+1)(x-2)`, so the solutions are `U(n) = a(-1)^n + b2^n` where `a` and `b` are any constants. Equivalently, `T(n) = a(-1)^n + b2^n - 1/2`, which is `Theta(2^n)` except in special cases.

Answer (score 2):

This recursion is called [non-homogeneous linear recurrence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations) and it is solved by converting it to a homogeneous one:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + 2T(n-2) + 1
T(n+1) = T(n) + 2T(n-1) + 1
```

Subtracting 1 from 2 and changing the base, you get `T(n) = 2 T(n-1) + T(n-2) - 2 T(n-3)`. The corresponding characteristic equation is:

```
x^3 - 2x^2 - x + 2 = 0
```

which has solutions `x = {-1, 1, 2}`. This means that the recursion looks like:

```
c1 * (-1)^n + c2 * 2^n + c3 * 1^n = c1 * 2^n + c2 (-1)^n + c3
```

Where all these constants can be found knowing T(0) and T(1). For your complexity analysis it is clear that this is exponential `O(2^n)`.